# How to join two columns and label category using DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two massive columns that I want to join together and then assign values to labels

```
ed_adm_order_md_dept    adm_order
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
     NaN                ADMIT FOR SURGERY
EMERGENCY MEDICINE      NaN
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
INTERNAL MEDICINE       NaN
ORTHOPEDIC SURGERY      NaN
                        ADMIT
                        ADMIT
                        ADMIT
```

output could be something like this

```
ed_adm_order_md_dept    
INTERNAL MEDICINE       
INTERNAL MEDICINE       
INTERNAL MEDICINE      
***ADMIT FOR SURGERY***                
EMERGENCY MEDICINE      
INTERNAL MEDICINE       
INTERNAL MEDICINE       
INTERNAL MEDICINE       
ORTHOPEDIC SURGERY      
    ADMIT       
ADMIT       
ADMIT
```

Comment: If that's  your example input, what exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: i edit my question you can see now how output i want to look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
df.ed_adm_order_md_dept.where(df.ed_adm_order_md_dept, df.adm_order)
```

That is, take the value of the first column where it exists, otherwise the second column.

Comment: can i save this value to new column or add numeric labels to it

Comment: @kero: Sure, `df['newstuff'] = MY_ANSWER_CODE`.  This is pretty basic Pandas.

Comment: i knew this part but what about if i want to label this categories with numeric values for example admit will be represent with 0 and surgery 1

Comment: @kero: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i knew this part but what about if i want to label this categories with numeric values for example admit will be represent with 0 and surgery 1

Comment: Then maybe `np.where(df.adm_order, 0, 1)`.